# Reactive variables as query parameters

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

After implementing apollo-client into my react app, I noticed that a lot of input data will probably end up in a reactive variable somewhere. And if I want to request anything to the server, often, the value will come from a reactive variable. So it would simplify my code a lot if I could link the value of the reactive variable to the parameters of my query. Ideally, what I would want is something like this:

```
gql`
query FirstName {
  firstName @client
}
query LastName {
  lastName @client
}

query user($firstName: ???, $lastName: ???){
  user(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    address
    dob
  }
}
`
```

Now, I understand that these requests would resolve in parallel, so the above would never work... But, how do I *make* it work? Do I need to add loadash just for this? Is there an apollo-client solution for this? How would I solve this with loadash or any other library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the @export directive, this [section](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/#using-local-only-fields-as-graphql-variables) of the docs explains how to use the local state as variables.

Your query would look like this

```
query user($firstName: ???, $lastName: ???){
  firstName @client @export(as: "firstName")
  lastName @client @export(as: "lastName")
  user(firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName){
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    address
    dob
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. I couldn't get export to work, but it was because I had an issue with my `InMemoryCache` definitions. After revising those, your example works as expected